# Django view not sending context data to ReactJS/Axios application

Tags: django, reactjs, axios

It appears I have come across very strange behavior. I am building a ReactJS+Django 3.0 application. Here is the problem...

I have a `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>` that wraps the form on the frontend.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post(paths.login, qs.stringify({
                email: emailVal,
                password: passwordVal
            }));
}
```

This works perfectly fine in sending data to the Django view! But when I try to then pass context variable through the Django view, it just fails completely. Meaning,

```
def login(request):
    data = {}
    '''
    Handle Logging in
    '''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = forms.LoginForm(request.POST)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            user = login_form.authenticate_user()
            #login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            data['errorMessage'] = ''
            for field, errors in login_form.errors.items():
                for error in errors:
                    data['errorMessage'] += error
    print(data)
    return render(request, 'index.html', context=data)
```

Given this, the data dictionary will be empty at first, but even when the `print(data)` shows that the data dictionary is populated, the context data that is sent to the `index.html` file is still empty.

WHY MIGHT THIS BE? I've been stuck on this forever.

I can work around this if I just use form submission instead of axios like this: `<form method='POST'>` However, I need to use axios. SOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the Django messages framework for this, which might be a better option (assuming you are re-rendering the page after POST):

```
from django.contrib import messages
def login(request):
    data = {}
    '''
    Handle Logging in
    '''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = forms.LoginForm(request.POST)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            user = login_form.authenticate_user()
            #login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            error_message = ''
            for field, errors in login_form.errors.items():
                for error in errors:
                    error_message += error
             messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, error_message)
    
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Then in your template (this is an example using Bootstrap, but you can modify it to fit your needs):

```
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            {% if message.tags == 'error' %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger alert-with-icon alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            {% else %}
                <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }} alert-with-icon alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            {% endif %}
                {{ message|safe }}
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

If you are sending data back as an AJAX JSON response instead:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
def login(request):
    data = {}
    '''
    Handle Logging in
    '''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = forms.LoginForm(request.POST)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            user = login_form.authenticate_user()
            #login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            error_message = ''
            for field, errors in login_form.errors.items():
                for error in errors:
                    error_message += error
            data['error_message'] = error_message
            return JsonResponse(data)
      else:
         return render(request, 'index.html')
```

In your Axios code:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post(paths.login, qs.stringify({
                email: emailVal,
                password: passwordVal
            }).then((response) => {
             //do something with JSON response
           }, (error) => {
             //do something with JSON response
           });
     });
```

Comment: What might the benefits be for using messages instead of context? Would I be able to pass JSON strings into messages as well?

Comment: Technically you can , but it wasn't really made for that - that is why I was asking if you were expecting a JSON response or not. I updated with an example that would return a JSON object that can be ingested from an AJAX function.

Comment: JsonResponse solved the problem for me! Thank you for preventing me from pulling my hair out :)

Comment: No problem! Glad to help!